# IntelliJ with Golang throws IllegalArgumentException

Tags: intellij-idea, go, intellij-plugin

I am encountering the following Problem:
When I try to add the Go-SDK to my Project, and select the GOROOT-Path (C:\Lib\Go), I get an `IllegalArgumentException`.

I googled it, and lots of People are encountering this issue.
One solution would be the Installation of a later golang-plugin for IntelliJ which is currently in the Alpha, but however when I download the source from github and open it in IntelliJ, I get lots of Errors, so I am unable to build it and create an executble jar-plugin. I think all dependencies should be directly in the Project integrated?!

Do you know other Solutions, or maybe an IDE with similiar Features like IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alpha version of the plugin doesn't require you to compile it.

Please follow the instructions in the readme, https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/#pre-release-builds, and you should be able to install it just fine.

> 1) Follow the instructions from here https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/managing-enterprise-plugin-repositories.html
>
> 2) Paste the url for the version you desire:
>
> - alpha: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugins/alpha/5047
> - nightly: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugins/nightly/5047